# How do I remove the 'Windows.Old' directory in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, temporary-files, windows.old

Besides simply right clicking on the file and selecting delete, is there another way to delete the `windows.old` folder?  Manually deleting the folder has proven to be rather tedious as I have to take ownership of the all folders and files and then delete as admin.

---

*Note: I'm **not** looking for the solution of taking ownership and deleting the `windows.old` folder.  I am looking for any solutions that are easier and unique to Windows 10.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete Windows.old in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/213670/how-do-i-delete-windows-old-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 while at face value, this may appear to be a duplicate, the answer is unique to Windows 10.  I also was hoping to avoid the accepted answer of your linked question.

Answer (score 1):

Following these steps *should* remove the contents from the `windows.old` folder:

1. Select Start, then Settings
2. Select Storage
3. Select Temp Files
4. Delete Previous Versions

This appears to be still a little buggy however, and takes some time if you have a large file size.

Comment: You wont see delete previous previous versions unless you run as administrator

Comment: @Keltari you mean as an administrator account?