# Deleting Windows.Old

Tags: windows-10, windows.old

I am the only user on my laptop.  I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10.  Anytime I try to delete the Windows.old folder, I get a prompt that says

> Folder Access Is Denied
>   You will need administrator privileges to delete this folder.

UAC is turned off.  Why am I unable to delete this folder?

**EDIT**
Yes, I have googled, I saw this post here, and tried to follow the instructions but no success

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-delete-the-windows-old-folder-from-windows-10/

**EDIT #2**

@Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 -- I have tried the solutions provided in both of the links you flagged as potential duplicates and neither solved my issue.

Comment: Did you actually google your problem? there are dozens of websites, blogs and even KB articles that contain the answer for your problem.

Comment: *Use the Cleanup Tool to delete this folder.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete Windows.old in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/213670/how-do-i-delete-windows-old-in-windows-7), [How do I remove the 'Windows.Old' directory in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/969669/how-do-i-remove-the-windows-old-directory-in-windows-10)

Comment: You are asking the same question as the proposed duplicate so as it stands, you can expect to get the same answers.  If you want different answers, you need to identify how your situation is different.  If you can't do that, describe exactly how the solutions didn't work (what happened, what messages, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Use Disk Cleanup to delete this folder or wait for 30 days

Comment: Already tried disk cleanup, it's been close to 60 days

Comment: How did you upgrade?. Did you boot from a DVD / USB to install Windows 10.My laptop automatically deleted `Windows.old` after 30 days from upgrading using Windows update

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of this question, too
[How do I remove the 'Windows.Old' directory in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/969669/how-do-i-remove-the-windows-old-directory-in-windows-10?lq=1)

From that question:
Settings App -> Storage -> Temp Files -> Delete Previous Versions
That should work on Windows 10

If that doesn't work, please show us the output, and why it didn't work/error message.